# ng repeat not pushing out data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have never really had an issue with using an `ng-repeat` before, however on this occasion i am not 100% sure what the problem is. I using a JSON file to feed data onto my DOM, when i call out fields within the JSON array i am not receiving any data based on my code below, am i doing something wrong?

```
"use strict"; 

  var app = angular.module("tickrApp", []);

 app.service("tickrService", function ($http, $q){
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('app/data/jobs.json').then(function (response){
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
});

this.getjobs = function () {
    return deferred.promise;
}
})

.controller('tickCtrl', function($scope, tickrService) {

var promise = tickrService.getjobs();
promise.then(function (data){

    $scope.jobs = data;
    console.log($scope.jobs);
});

 });
```

html

```
        <div data-ng-repeat="newJobs in jobs">

            <div>{{jobs.sector}}</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include your `script.js` after angular.

Also, replace this :

```
$scope.jobs = data;
```

with this :

```
$scope.jobs = data.jobs;
```

And in the themplate `newJob` should be `job`.

**See [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qnR4lHcCCKn5ENdZLP62?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Like said in another answer you have to load angular.js before the script.js file

```
$scope.jobs = data;
```

has to be

```
$scope.jobs = data.jobs;
```

and

```
<div>{{ jobs.sector }}</div>
```

has to be

```
<div>{{ newJobs.sector }}</div>
```